# search for a text in text files present in 25 different folders

Tags: text, full-text-search, editor

I have 25 folders where logs are recorded, and in each folder there is a text document created. Each time when i want to search for a "string" lot of time is wasted for manual work in searching all those 25 folders. can you please suggest some thing for this ?

Comment: Have you heard about Grep tools?

Comment: do you want to write something yourself in C# or are you asking for a 3-rd party tool?

Answer (score 1):

try to use notepad++ find in files...
[image]

Comment: manual work here kind of using ctrl+f in all 25 files and doing this for 10 different texts is tooo waste of time . so

Comment: @vinaykumar in notepad++ we can search in a folder , in all files present in it , please see the image properly

Comment: including sub folders!

Comment: @vinaykumar I guess the 25 Folders are not in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem for win, then one answer is TotalCommander.

http://imgur.com/a/F46kN

Answer (score 0):

Use Lucene.Net. Find the below link to know more

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms